# Best way to add a lightbox to a pre-existing portfolio page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to add lightbox functionality on https://www.nycofficesuites.com/gallery/ only, without redoing the entire portfolio section.

I purchased a commercial theme and tweaked it to build this site.

I've seen information on both plugins and doing this without a plugin.  What's the best way to add the lightbox feature while minimizing complications/ potential conflicts?  The site is live so I want to be very careful.  Thanks!

Comment: Go [here](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and put the script and the css inside (with the images) and enqueue them in functions.php. Then find your `page-template-template-portfolio.php` file and find the wrapper that controls the image output, and modify them according to lightbox documentation.